# Kimoto Gravity Well Issue?

Tags: algorithm, ubuntu, cryptography, bitcoind, blockchain

Can anybody explain what this code actually do and how it is re targeted the difficulty. I want my difficulty to be re targeted every 60 seconds, searching on internet find that this function will re targeted the difficulty.

I am working on Logos LGS coin.

```
unsigned int static KimotoGravityWell(const CBlockIndex* pindexLast, const CBlockHeader *pblock, uint64 TargetBlocksSpacingSeconds, uint64 PastBlocksMin, uint64 PastBlocksMax) {
        /* current difficulty formula - kimoto gravity well */
        const CBlockIndex *BlockLastSolved                                = pindexLast;
        const CBlockIndex *BlockReading                                = pindexLast;
        const CBlockHeader *BlockCreating                                = pblock;
                                                BlockCreating                                = BlockCreating;
        uint64                                PastBlocksMass                                = 0;
        int64                                PastRateActualSeconds                = 0;
        int64                                PastRateTargetSeconds                = 0;
        double                                PastRateAdjustmentRatio                = double(1);
        CBigNum                                PastDifficultyAverage;
        CBigNum                                PastDifficultyAveragePrev;
        double                                EventHorizonDeviation;
        double                                EventHorizonDeviationFast;
        double                                EventHorizonDeviationSlow;

    if (BlockLastSolved == NULL || BlockLastSolved->nHeight == 0 || (uint64)BlockLastSolved->nHeight < PastBlocksMin) { return bnProofOfWorkLimit.GetCompact(); }

        for (unsigned int i = 1; BlockReading && BlockReading->nHeight > 0; i++) {
                if (PastBlocksMax > 0 && i > PastBlocksMax) { break; }
                PastBlocksMass++;

                if (i == 1)        { PastDifficultyAverage.SetCompact(BlockReading->nBits); }
                else                { PastDifficultyAverage = ((CBigNum().SetCompact(BlockReading->nBits) - PastDifficultyAveragePrev) / i) + PastDifficultyAveragePrev; }
                PastDifficultyAveragePrev = PastDifficultyAverage;

                PastRateActualSeconds                        = BlockLastSolved->GetBlockTime() - BlockReading->GetBlockTime();
                PastRateTargetSeconds                        = TargetBlocksSpacingSeconds * PastBlocksMass;
                PastRateAdjustmentRatio                        = double(1);
                if (PastRateActualSeconds < 0) { PastRateActualSeconds = 0; }
                if (PastRateActualSeconds != 0 && PastRateTargetSeconds != 0) {
                PastRateAdjustmentRatio                        = double(PastRateTargetSeconds) / double(PastRateActualSeconds);
                }
                EventHorizonDeviation                        = 1 + (0.7084 * pow((double(PastBlocksMass)/double(144)), -1.228));
                EventHorizonDeviationFast                = EventHorizonDeviation;
                EventHorizonDeviationSlow                = 1 / EventHorizonDeviation;

                if (PastBlocksMass >= PastBlocksMin) {
                        if ((PastRateAdjustmentRatio <= EventHorizonDeviationSlow) || (PastRateAdjustmentRatio >= EventHorizonDeviationFast)) { assert(BlockReading); break; }
                }
                if (BlockReading->pprev == NULL) { assert(BlockReading); break; }
                BlockReading = BlockReading->pprev;
        }

        CBigNum bnNew(PastDifficultyAverage);
        if (PastRateActualSeconds != 0 && PastRateTargetSeconds != 0) {
                bnNew *= PastRateActualSeconds;
                bnNew /= PastRateTargetSeconds;
        }
    if (bnNew > bnProofOfWorkLimit) { bnNew = bnProofOfWorkLimit; }



return bnNew.GetCompact();
}
```

Comment: What do you not understand? "Explain a piece of code" is not really a concise question. You know that there is [this bitcoin sister site](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com), right?

Comment: I didn't understand how this fucntion retarget difficulty and what is the use of EventHorizonDeviation variable etc.